# IPv6 - number of networks

Tags: ipv6

How do you calculate the number of networks for 12AA:44EF:5555::12BC:3344:22/53?

Comment: Your question is a little vague, have a look at this link to maybe restate it more clearly....https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/66991/ipv6-subnetting-overview-and-case-study

Comment: You figure it the same way that you do with IPv4: binary math. For example, if you mean how many standard 64-bit networks, then it is  `64-53=11` bits for your networks, which is `2^11=2048`64-bit networks for your `/53` prefix. If you mean how many 127-bit point-to-point networks, then you are looking at `2^74` 127-bit networks, a number too large to actually matter.

Comment: Thanks for the response back, Guys. Ron gave the answer I was looking for because I did not realize you calculate IPv6 the same way as IPv4 with the 2^ equation. Thanks again!

Comment: @RonMaupin: You should make this an answer. It makes the question answered, Jay can accept it and not everyone reads in the comments. (And comments are not for answers anyway).

Comment: @Dubu, I have been out for a couple of weeks. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You figure it the same way that you do with IPv4: binary math. For example, if you mean how many standard 64-bit networks, then it is `64-53=11` bits for your networks, which is `2^11=2048` 64-bit networks for your `/53` prefix. If you mean how many 127-bit point-to-point networks, then you are looking at `2^74` 127-bit networks, a number too large to actually matter.